# Are fluent Esperanto speakers in demand?

Tags: native-speakers

I heard from someone that fluent Esperanto speakers are in high demand.

Is this true? If so, what are they in demand for?

Comment: Who was the someone? The only possibility would be tutoring people in Esperanto, surely?

Comment: @AndrewWoods Esperanists may be needed for translation to and/or from texts in Esperanto, or to serve as translators between people whose best common tongue is Esperanto, among other possibilities.